# Этимология словосочетания "космический корабль"

Tags: этимология

В [Викисловаре](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8C#.D0.AD.D1.82.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.BE.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B3.D0.B8.D1.8F) про этимологию сказано следующее:

> Словосочетание впервые употреблено в коммюнике о запуске первого
>   космического корабля (корабля-спутника) 15 мая 1960 г., составленном
>   Сергеем Павловичем Королёвым, Мстиславом Всеволодовичем Келдышем,
>   Александром Юльевичем Ишлинским и Львом Архиповичем Гришиным.

Эта же история почти дословно дублируется во множестве других источников.

С другой стороны, в 1924 г. К.Э.Циолковский назвал одну из своих статей "Космический корабль" ([здесь](http://www.ras.ru/ktsiolkovskyarchive/1_actview.aspx?id=46) можно видеть скан-копии рукописи). Статья не была опубликована сразу, но вошла в сборник сочинений, который вышел в 1956 г. С большой вероятностью кто-то из великих учёных, упомянутых в приведенной цитате, мог быть знаком с этой работой (хотя бы на уровне названия). При этом я не исключаю, что самый первый автор растиражированной байки не слышал о работе К.Э.Циолковского и искренне считал, что словосочетание впервые появилось в 1960 г.

Попытка упомянуть в Викисловаре статью К.Э.Циолковского была пресечена "опытным участником" без каких либо пояснений (там действует политика премодерации).

Вопросы к знатокам, знакомым с методологией этимологии: (а) является ли корректной приведенная в Викисловаре трактовка? (б) уместна ли ссылка на работу К.Э.Циолковского в разделе этимологии данной статьи?

Comment: _С другой стороны, в 1924 г. К.Э.Циолковский назвал одну из своих статей "Космический корабль"_ === А в 1915 г. (по данным Нацкорпуса) вышла книга Перельмана "Межпланетные путешествия". Там тоже говорилось о космических кораблях: _Люди в таком снаряде ― изобретатель заранее окрестил его «Ракетой» ― будут при помощи особого механизма направлять истечение газов в любую сторону. Это будет настоящий управляемый **космический корабль**._ (Ссылку дам в след. комментарии.)

Comment: http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%EA%EE%F1%EC%E8%F7%E5%F1%EA%E8%E9&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%EA%EE%F0%E0%E1%EB%FC&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=&p=52&docid=105377&sid=671

Comment: @slava1947 Вот спасибо! Похоже, это словосочетание было уже тогда на слуху.

Comment: @slava1947 - я почти не сомневался, что Ц. не был первым.  Но тут, правда, одно но. Перельман был хорошо знаком с Ц., даже редактировал часть его работ. Так что и тут бабка надвое сказала, кто из Петров Ивановичей первым сказал "Эээээ"!

Comment: *Похоже, это словосочетание было уже тогда на слуху* - вряд ли уж так "на слуху", но следи какого-то узкого круга энтузиастов (помимо Ц. и П. возможно Мещерский, Жуковский - они хоть и аэродинамики всё больше, то всё-таки...) - безусловно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас помимо двух явных вопросов ещё столько скрытых... 
Ну попробую изложить последовательно.

(1) Перво-наперво. Проблема не относится к этимологии в строгом понимании слова. Я бы классифицировал вопрос как терминологический или историко-терминологический.

Теперь на ваши вопросы.

(2)

> (а) является ли корректной приведенная в Викисловаре трактовка?

Это не вопрос филологии. Да, конечно, она корректна, ибо основана на документах.

(3)

> б) уместна ли ссылка на работу К.Э. Циолковского в разделе этимологии данной статьи?

С учетом (1) - да, вполне. Но только ссылка - см. (5).

(4)

> С другой стороны, в 1924 г. К.Э. Циолковский назвал одну из своих
>   статей "Космический корабль" (здесь можно видеть скан-копии рукописи).

Это известный факт.

(5)

> Статья не была опубликована сразу, но вошла в сборник сочинений,
>   который вышел в 1956 г. С большой вероятностью кто-то из великих
>   учёных, упомянутых в приведенной цитате, мог быть знаком с этой
>   работой (хотя бы на уровне названия).

Рассуждения и догадки не могут быть приняты в расчет при установлении авторства термина. Чтобы говорить о приоритете Циолковского надо иметь достаточно весомый набор условий. Перво-наперво установить, что гипотетический объект, названный Ц-ким "КК", и  упоминаемый в сообщении "корабль-спутник" суть одно и то же в техническом понимании. Последнее реально возможно, только если автор современного термина укажет на источник заимствования. Иначе - вряд ли, больно уж разные это в техническом отношении вещи... (Небольшое отступление. Лев Успенский в "Слове о словах" приводит несколько фактов разительной перемены значения слов. Например, *вратарь* или *велосипед*. При этом, хотя некоторая смысловая общность сохранялась, но объекты стали совершенно другими).

(6)

> При этом я не исключаю, что самый первый автор растиражированной байки
>   не слышал о работе К.Э.Циолковского и искренне считал, что
>   словосочетание впервые появилось в 1960 г.

Вот только "байкой" не надо называть официальную информацию. Она документирована. Что касается чтения статьи Ц-го кем-то из авторов, то это вполне возможно. Но никак не сказывается на самом отношении к приоритету - см. (5).

(7)
На моей памяти автором термина открыто называли С. П. Королёва. Якобы именно он предложил и настоял. А он Циолковского безусловно читал.

(8)
В самом названии нет ничего удивительного, думаю, что подобное впервые пришло в голову кому-то задолго до Ц. Если не ошибаюсь, ещё Свифт говорил о летающих кораблях. Если не он, так Кампанелла. Да и термин "воздухоплавание" тоже старше Ц-го. Так что в тот момент, когда внеземную Вселенную впервые назвали "космосом", оставалось только перенести туда "корабль" - по аналогии с воздушны судном.

(9)
Вот почему воздушное - судно, а космический - корабль, вот это реально было бы интересно узнать. Но увы, на такие вопросы лингвистика ответов как правило не дает. Ибо прямой причины на то нет. Божиим провидением, как говорится.

(10)
Совет. С "Викисловарем" не связывайтесь. Ну их к Богу. Тем более, что позиция у вас в общем-то не такая уж и бесспорная и прочная.

*Простите, опечатки исправлю позже, что-то я притомился. Если кто-то поможет, возражать не буду.*

*Опечатки исправил*

Comment: Хороший ответ, спасибо! Я принимаю всё, кроме п.6 -- ошибка в изложении фактов ("словосочетание впервые употреблено") не может быть оправдана их документированностью. Хотя контекст употребления важен -- с этим я согласен.

Comment: Не Компанелла, а Кампанелла.

Comment: Возможно, для этимологии важно, что начиная с этого коммюнике словосочетание "космический корабль" вошло в язык в качестве устойчивого сочетания для определённого класса объектов (пусть до этого оно сколько угодно использовалось среди многих похожих выражений). Такая интерпретация меня убедила бы.

Comment: *user31264* *Не Компанелла, а Кампанелла* - да, конечно,спасибо. .

Comment: *ошибка в изложении фактов ("словосочетание впервые употреблено") не может быть оправдана их документированностью* - здесь нет фактической ошибки как таковой. Под "впервые употреблено" понимается адресное, осознанное, научно оправданное, *послужившее основой дальнейшего применения*. Упоминание Ц. в связи с приоритетом возможно и даже полезно, но не как опровержение, а лишь точности ради.

Comment: (+)Никто не собирается же оспаривать приоритет Колумба на то основании, что до него на американском континенте побывали викинги, до них - китайцы, до китайцев предположительно - полинезийцы, эскимосы (это точно), а первыми вообще были индейцы. К стати в Википедии в статье о Ц. этот факт приводится - и возражений не вызывает. .

Comment: *Возможно, для этимологии важно, что начиная с этого коммюнике словосочетание* - важно. Но не для "этимологии", а для истории. Этимология не занимается историей возникновения словосочетаний. Кстати не столь уж существенно именно "вхождение в язык", достаточно было бы одного факта преемственности  употребления. Если бы кто-то воспользовался термином "КК" на основании работ Ц., этого было бы достаточно.

Comment: @behemothus Да, приоритет Колумба никто не оспаривает. В то же время никто не назовёт корректной фразу "Колумб первым из европейцев посетил Америку" -- хотя бы в силу задокументированных фактов о Лейфе Эрикссоне. Впрочем, англовики в этом вопросе идёт ещё дальше: _Эрикссон был "the first known European to have discovered North America [...] before Christopher Columbus"._ С остальным мне теперь сколько-то понятно, спасибо.